# How to get the integer primary key value of a last column value in a particular column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following table structure

```
_id   column1    column2   column3  column4

1      abcd1      abcd2      abcd3    qbcd4
2      efgh1      efgh2      efgh3    efgh4
3      blah1                 blah3    blah4
5      blll1                          
8      hsdhj               
.........
.........
```

Now I want update the value of column3 where _id = 5;

But Now at Run time in my android app how would I know that _id is `5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but try this:

```
UPDATE table SET column3 = "new value" WHERE _id = (SELECT min(_id) FROM table WHERE column3 is null);
```

This will update row 5's `column3` with what new value you want.

This assumes that you do not have:

```
_id   column1    column2   column3  column4

1      abcd1      abcd2      abcd3    qbcd4
2      efgh1      efgh2      efgh3    efgh4
3      blah1                          blah4
5      blll1                          
6      blah1                 blah3    blah4
8      hsdhj
9      wdenm
...
```

And you want _id = 8.